# What does "plumb near" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Sling Blade (1996)*, Karl kills Dixon with a sling blade:

> Karl: I went in the house...and I hit Jesse Dixon upside the head with
> it... knocked him off my mother. I reckon that didn't satisfy me... so
> I hit him again in the neck with the sharp edge... and just **plumb near**
> cut his head off, killed him.

What does "plumb near" mean? Is he just emphasizing that he very swiftly cut Dixon's head off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "very nearly". He **almost** cut his head off.
The word *plumb* can mean *completely*, but that is contradicted by *near*, so in this sentence *plumb* is an intensifier for the word *near*.

Answer (score 5):

I encourage you to check dictionaries before asking. The usage you're looking for is somewhat colloquial and is an adverb; here are a few entries:

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plumb): *chiefly dialectal* : to a complete degree : ABSOLUTELY
- [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/plumb): *North American [as submodifier]* To a very high degree; extremely.
  ‘they must both be plumb crazy’